# niosii processor Altera C program

Tags: c, intel-fpga, nios, qsys

I'm currently working on the Altera DE0 board with the QuartusII Web Edition software. I need to use a nios processor on Qsys to display a shifted signal from a GPIO pin on my board. The input signal would be a clock signal from an external source. The problem is that I have no idea how I can write a program in C (on the Eclipse IDE) for diplaying a delayed clock on an oscilloscope.
My Qsys design looks like that [Image1 => Qsys Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzAEC.png) and here the Eclipse IDE where I have to write my C program [Image2 => Eclipse IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ0KU.png)
Please help me !
thank you very much in advance for the replies

Answer (score 0):

start with the system.h file to know which base_address is assigned to each peripherial, then you can use pointers to directly access the GPIO or use the IORD/IOWR functions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).